# Algorithm for contour matching of points

Tags: c++, computer-vision, feature-detection

Say I have an outline of an object in 2D space defined by a set of points as a reference outline and I start trying to trace the outline starting from any point and the algorithm should then be able to say to which part of the reference outline the current trace belongs to...

How could I actually go about achieving this? Are there any concepts of feature / contour detection that  can I abstract this problem to?

Comment: Have a look at www.vtk.org

Comment: Have you looked at Chain code? If you need the matching to be rotational invariant, then have a look at Boundary Centered Polar Encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some popular shape matching algorithms,

http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~malik/papers/BMP-shape.pdf
http://www.cs.umd.edu/~djacobs/pubs_files/ID-pami-8.pdf
http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/users/vashok/MyPapers/HighlySelectiveConf2010/liu_cvpr2010.pdf

which give a similarity between two shapes. Some even try to incorporate deformation/articulation invariant shape matching in their framework.

Code can be found here,
https://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/shape/sc_digits.html
http://www.dabi.temple.edu/~hbling/code_data.htm

If you want to do sub-part matching, you can try to run these algorithms with one shape fixed and match parts of other shape at different sizes